# Meteor error on fast-rendering path TypeError: dynamics.slice is not a function

Tags: meteor

I receive the following error every time a page renders. I didn't receive these before, they just started one day and the only solution I found until now is to uninstall fast-render. Changing the routes in any way doesn't seem to have any effect. Any idea what the source of the problem could be?

[image: Error]

I found the following page which describes a similar error, but I don't have this.redirect(...) or Router.go(...) in a waitOn function:
https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render#3-waiton-and-subscriptions-methods

Here is the code for the Account Route and the corresponding controller:

```
Router.route("/account", {
    name: "Account",
    controller: simpleWebsiteController,
    waitOn: function () {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe("userData"),
            Meteor.subscribe("userMessages")
        ]
    },
    data: function () {
        var messages = Collections.Messages.find({userId: Meteor.userId()},{sort: { creationDate: -1 }});
        var posts = Collections.Posts.find({});
        var comments = Collections.Comments.find({});
        return {
            content: "page-account",
            userMessages: messages,
            userComments: comments,
            userPosts: posts
        };
    },
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        // If the user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        var path = this.location.get().path;
        if (!Meteor.userId() && path.indexOf("/login") != 0)
            this.location.go("/login");
        else
            this.next();
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
var simpleWebsiteController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: "MainLayout",
    waitOn: function () {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe("userData"),
            Meteor.subscribe("categoriesList"),
            Meteor.subscribe("cityData")
        ]
    },
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        // If the user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        var path = this.location.get().path;
        if (!Meteor.userId() && path.indexOf("/login") != 0)
            this.location.go("/login");
        else
            this.next();
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
      $('.row-offcanvas').removeClass('active');
      $('.collapse').removeClass('active');
    },
    fastRender: true
});
```

Comment: You should share your code as well, otherwise it would be impossible to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure where the source of the problem is, so I'm not sure which parts of the code to share. The route configuration doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: Share your `/account/...` route description.

Comment: I also had the same problem when I tried to follow a tutorial from themeteorchef. You can check the package in meteor/package to see if you have installed the package of method that you call it to use in your code or not. This problem might be because you use the method but you don't install its package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9003#issuecomment-321803612) for more information about the reason of this error.

---

Unfortunately the fast-render package that flow-router has as a dependency is messing around with meteor internals and would break your code as meteor's core code gets updated.

You can clone and edit kadira's fast-render and fix this problem.

Go to **packages** folder under your project's directory

```
cd your_project_dir/packages/

git clone https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render.git
```

Then, edit **your_project_dir/packages/fast-render/lib/server/context.js** like so on line 23:

```
// support for Meteor.user
// Fibers.current._meteor_dynamics = {};
Fibers.current._meteor_dynamics = []; // <-- Fixed
```

Now this will overwrite kadira's v2.16.0 fast-render package.

Answer (score 1):

this package update was the guilty in my case:

`meteor@1.7.0 -> meteor@1.7.1`

Edit `packages` and/or `versions` files and should be ok.